# React filepond adjustment

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, npm

I am new in **react**.

I want to use [filepond](https://itnext.io/uploading-files-with-react-and-filepond-f8a798308557) for uploading image and preview

But I want to put an image in horizontal,

Anyone have an idea how I can do this, thanks

I want to be horizontal with scroller like below:

[image: horizontal with scroller]

Comment: You can add bootstrap className row and cols right to display them in a row?

Comment: Hi, FilePond dev here. The rendering and positioning of the items are done internally (because it's all animated). Currently, there's no way to reposition the items without rewriting part of the list source code.